# Як правильно: порок чи вада?

Tags: вибір-слова, калька

Є безліч статей на українській мові про "*порок серця*". І це не дивно, оскільки [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/porok) надає такий приклад. Та чи не є це слово російською калькою? Чи не було б краще вживати в українській мові слово "*вада*"? Знайшла думку щодо цього на "Культура мови на щодень":

ВАДА — ПОРОК.

> У масовій свідомості побутує назва хвороби порок серця. Як свідчить медична література, порок серця — це не одна якась конкретна хвороба серця, а загальне означення вад серця. Лікують природжені і набуті вади. Серед них розрізняють клапанні, ревматичні, органічні, декомпенсовані. Термін порок серця вказує у спеціальній літературі на фізичну недугу внаслідок захворювання, а також природжену. Закономірно постає питання: чи можлива взаємозаміна слів порок і вада у терміні?
>
> З огляду на зміст, який передають згадані іменники, слово вада однозначніше і конкретніше, напр.: Найбільша вада штучних, а головне синтетичних тканин — негігієнічність, некомфортність! (з журн.); Вада зору, при якій зображення віддалених предметів утворюється за сітківкою, називається далекозорістю (з підр.).
>
> Іменник порок, як правило, негативно характеризує осіб (риси поведінки, фізичні дані, умови і спосіб життя тощо): Його [Нерона] душа — ціла клоака всяких пороків, які могли зустрітися серед роду людського (М. Слабошпицький); Бідність — не порок, а велике горе (прислів’я).
>
> У сучасній мовній практиці трапляються випадки ненормативного вживання слова порок у значенні «вада, недолік»: Контейнер [технологія товароруху з застосуванням тари обладнання] допоможе торгівлі викоренити пороки, котрі давно набридли, — обмірювання, обважування, обрахування (з газ.). У таких випадках треба дотримуватися літературної норми і відповідно послуговуватися словами вада, недолік.
>
> Щодо терміна порок серця, то впадає у вічі небажана синонімія першого слова з розмовним порок, через що термін сприймається як калька з російської мови. Тому замість порок серця варто вживати вада серця, напр.: На початку нашого століття були безпорадні перед ревматичною клапанною вадою серця (з газ.).

А як щодо іншого означення слова "порок" - 2. заст. Аморальна поведінка, розпуста. Карав він [пророк] сміливо порок, Життя осуджував негоже (Павло Грабовський, I, 1959, 140).
Можливо його також краще замінити? На "*розпуста*", чи "*гріх*", наприклад?

Answer (score 2):

Лексема **"порок" НЕ є калькою з російської мови**. Для підтвердження наведу статтю з [Етимологічного словника, том 4, ст. 524](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf):

> **порок** - **вада**, хиба. А порочний - той, який має пороки; розпусний; хибний. Це слово було ще в давньоруській мові (себто українській): "др. порокъ - недолік, вада; нарі­кання, докір". А також зафіксоване в болгарській, білоруській тощо.

Цікаво, що там же пише, що це слово:

> через давньоруське посередництво *запо­зичено зі старослов'янської мови*; стсл. nорокъ "догана, докір, хула", як і вл. porok "осуд, гана; ***недолік***".

Зважаючи на статтю, що Ви кинули, а також і визгачення слова "вада", яке подає [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6375&page=233):

> **ВА́ДА** и, ж. 1. ***Недосконалість***, ***недолік***. *Приклад*:  Санька рано пізнала горе, а її *вада – німота* – зробила її відлюдком (Григорій Тютюнник);
>
> 2. Несправність, пошкодження (коли йдеться про річ, наприклад, годинник);
> 3. Те, що шкодить, має шкідливий вплив.

Виходить, що "вада" - поняття вужче, конкретніше (вада зору; вада - німота тощо). "Порок - ширше понятт і використовується як загальне означення вад серця.

Проте сам термін "порок серця" є усталеним і навіть зафіксованим у словниках, зокрема і СУМ-11. Також сьогодні ці два слова у значенні "недолік" серця використовуються як взаємозамінні. Наприклад, у статті [Вроджені вади серця у дорослих](http://cardio.org.ua/ua/news/vrodzheni-vady-sertsia-u-doroslykh) (Центр дитячої кардіології) читаємо:

> Вроджені *вади серця* можна діагностувати до народження, відразу після народження, в дитинстві чи взагалі не діагностувати до повноліття. Можливі випадки, коли у дорослої людини є вроджений *порок серця*, який протікає абсолютно безсимптомно.

Отже, слово "***порок***" не є калькою з російської і відрізняється від "***вада***" лише "відтінком" у значеннях (вужче - ширше).

P. S. : На мою думку, сьогодні частіше використовують словосполучення "вада серця". Я теж прихильник використання саме такої словосполуки. Однак і "порок серця" теж правильно.

Ймовірним залишається і той варіант, що на підсвідомому рівні хочеться уникнути русизмів або ж слів, що їх "нагадують".

Comment: [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) з вами не погоджується, *порок* в значенні *дефект* перекладається як *вада*.